# identify start and end terms of NA sections

Tags: r, na

Let's say I have some data in `R` that looks like this:

```
c(0.11, NA, NA, NA, 2.76, 3.65, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1.56)
```

How might I efficiently extract the start and end terms of each "block" of `NA` values?  If the result were a data frame, I would want it to look something like this:

```
  first.na last.na
1        2       4
2        7      10
```

I'm trying to train myself to avoid `for` loops since I'll be doing this type of operation on very large datasets (on the order of 1e9 terms), and `na.omit` isn't quite helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe there is a function to do that work, but you can do by:

```
> z <- c(0.11, NA, NA, NA, 2.76, 3.65, NA, NA, NA, NA, 6)

> z2 <- diff(is.na(c(0, z, 0)))
> data.frame(first.na = which(z2 == 1), last.na = which(z2 == -1)-1)
  first.na last.na
1        2       4
2        7      10
```